# Xcode 9 sendSubviewToBack bug

Tags: objective-c, xcode9

The sendSubviewToBack method on a tableView doesn't seem to work in Xcode 9.

The concerned view which needs to be sent to back is still displayed at the top of the edge. That's kind of strange.

Is it a bug on the simulator ?

Does anyone have the same issue ?

Comment: I have the same issue on device can you file an Apple Report bug?

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney Please, you will find the Apple Report Bug through that link : https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=34807222

Comment: I will keep you informed :-)

Comment: cheers! Also none of the others work either insertSubview atIndex for tableViews. Setting the background view works so I would suggest adding multiple views to one view, and then setting them as the tableView background. Still doesn't work as before...

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney could please send me a sample project which resume the concerned issue if you have it ? Thank you (I'll give you my mail address). Apple asked me if we could provide them a sample project demonstrating the problem.

Comment: since my code is both interface builder and code I will have to send them my whole code base - will do this by filing my own apple report